# Background service is not working in some devices like vivo , mi etc.. after app is clear from recent app

Tags: service, background

i am use the below code to send the location to the server but it is not working in some devices after app is clear from recent app. so what is best alternate way to start service when app is closed.

```
public class GpsService extends Service implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    String mLastUpdateTime;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

    SharePref sharePref;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e("sevice start", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>......");
        sharePref = new SharePref(GpsService.this);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
                .setContentTitle("My Awesome App")
                .setContentText("Doing some work...")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        startForeground(1337, notification);

        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    // Update UI with location data
                    // ...
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), locationResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            ;
        };

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("sevice start", "mGoogleApiClient >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>......");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    //Check Google play is available or not


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        startLocationUpdates();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //Save your location
        Log.e("GpsService Location lat", "Is change " + location.getLatitude());
        Log.e("Gps Location long", "Is change " + location.getLongitude());
        Log.e("GpsService userid", "Enter" + sharePref.getUserId());

        Toast.makeText(GpsService.this, location.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        sharePref.SetLat(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
        sharePref.SetLong(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

        String lati = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        String longi = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

        HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<>();
        param.put(PARAM_USER_ID, sharePref.getUserId());
        param.put(PARAM_SESSION_ID, sharePref.getSessionId());
        param.put(PARAM_LAT, lati);
        param.put(PARAM_LONG, longi);
        param.put(PARAM_PLATFORM, PLATFORM);

        BikerService.addLatLong(GpsService.this, param, new APIService.Success<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {

                Log.e("Location Response-->", "" + response.toString());
                BikerParser.AddLatLongResponse AddLatLongResponse = BikerParser.AddLatLongResponse.addLatLongResponse(response);
                if (AddLatLongResponse.getStatusCode() == API_STATUS_FOUR_ZERO_ONE) {
                    stopService(new Intent(GpsService.this, GpsService.class));
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Log.e("sevice start", "startLocationUpdates >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>......");
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");

    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you got the solution?

Comment: actually background service is not support longer in new android version because of battery backup so in android orieo 8.0 google remove the concept of background service